# SVG symbol called via use attribute not rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, rotation

I'm in the process of creating a circular menu using SVG. There's going to be five parts in total, with each piece being built using an SVG path element. I also have an icon generated via a use attribute. It calls a symbol attribute that defines the SVG icon.

The issue I'm running into is that Firefox (v45.0.1, latest version as today for me) for some reason isn't rendering the icon at all. I noticed that if I inspect the SVG element, the symbol section is grayed out in Firefox (whereas in Chrome, it's not).

On the second example I've posted, I noticed that when inspecting the use element, it's not rotated like it should be, almost as if Firefox is ignoring the rotation attribute entirely.

The first example is built off the original code where I first noticed the issue. The second one mentioned earlier is a variation where I modified the SVG code to be a specific size, as the original dimensions I was handed over by a designer wasn't in the 0,0 coordinates --- not sure if this is an issue since it didn't cause an issue in any other browsers besides Firefox.

Any ideas what the cause may be? I have the examples collapsed since the code is a bit long with both of them visible at once (let me know if you guys would prefer one to be made visible and I can update it).

(Note that due to how it's setup, you'll need to scroll some to the left and the right to see the segment I have visible, depending on your screen settings.)

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper svg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    touch-action: none;
    transform: matrix3d(0.59051, -0.80703, 0, 0, 0.80703, 0.59051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.59051, -0.80703, 0, 0, 0.80703, 0.59051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.wrapper svg symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}
.wrapper svg a {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.wrapper svg #item-procurement .sector {
    fill: #f8ba10;
    stroke: #f8ba10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 978px;">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-2 -2 504 504" id="menu">
        <g id="symbolsContainer">
         <symbol class="icon" id="icon-procurement-desktop" viewBox="0 0 39 39">
          <g>
           <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M25.9,44.8v63.1h111h3.1V44.8H25.9z M139.3,107.2h-2.4H26.6V45.6h112.7V107.2z"></path>
           <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" class="st2" d="M101.1,107.6"></path>
           
           <rect stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" x="31.9" y="51.1" width="0.8" height="50.7"></rect>
           
           <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M115.7,49.6H50.2v0.8h27.9c-6.5,2-11.1,8.1-11.1,15.2v21.2c0,7.1,4.7,13.2,11.1,15.2H50.2v0.8h65.4V102H87.8c6.5-2,11.1-8.1,11.1-15.2V65.5c0-7.1-4.7-13.2-11.1-15.2h27.9C115.7,50.3,115.7,49.6,115.7,49.6z M98.2,65.5v21.2c0,8.4-6.8,15.2-15.2,15.2s-15.2-6.8-15.2-15.2V65.5c0-8.4,6.8-15.2,15.2-15.2C91.3,50.3,98.2,57.1,98.2,65.5z"></path>
           <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M36.3,59.4L36.3,59.4v-0.8c0,0,3.4,0,5.8-2.4c1.7-1.6,2.5-4.1,2.5-7.2h0.8c0,3.3-0.9,5.9-2.8,7.7C40.1,59.3,36.8,59.4,36.3,59.4z"></path>
           <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M45.4,103.8h-0.8c0-3.1-0.9-5.5-2.5-7.2c-2.4-2.4-5.8-2.4-5.8-2.4v-0.8c0.1,0,3.7,0,6.4,2.6C44.5,97.9,45.4,100.5,45.4,103.8z"></path>
    
           <rect stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" x="32.2" y="113.4" width="108" height="0.8"></rect>
           <rect stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" x="42.8" y="119.1" width="97.4" height="0.8"></rect> 
          </g>
         </symbol>
    
        </g>
        
        <g id="itemsContainer"> 
         <a class="item" id="item-procurement" role="link" tabindex="0" transform="matrix(-0.80901,0.58778,-0.58778,-0.80901,599.2005616668552,305.30793552061857)" data-svg-origin="250 250">
          <path d="M415,250 l85,0 A250,250 0 0,0 327.25424859373686,12.235870926211618 l-26.26644452187054,80.83980388508806 A165,165 0 0,1 415,250" class="sector"></path>
          <use xlink:href="#icon-procurement-desktop" width="21" height="21" x="370.12713623046875" y="92.61793518066406" transform="rotate(-90 413.62713623046875 131.11793518066406)"></use>
         </a>  
        </g>
                
       </svg>
    </div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper svg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    touch-action: none;
    transform: matrix3d(0.59051, -0.80703, 0, 0, 0.80703, 0.59051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.59051, -0.80703, 0, 0, 0.80703, 0.59051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.wrapper svg symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}
.wrapper svg a {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.wrapper svg #item-procurement .sector {
    fill: #f8ba10;
    stroke: #f8ba10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 978px;">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-2 -2 504 504" id="menu">
  <g id="symbolsContainer">
   <symbol class="icon" id="icon-procurement-desktop" viewBox="0 0 19 15.81">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <rect stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" x="1.2" y="1.4" width="3" height="0.1"/>
                        <rect stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" x="1.2" y="2.4" width="4.6" height="0.1"/>
                        <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M8.5,5"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M17,6.4V0H0v13.5h12.5L11,15.8h8V3.3L17,6.4z M0.1,13.4V0.1h16.8v6.4l-1.1,1.6V2.4H8.4v3.1H1.3v6h7.3v-0.9h5.8l-1.8,2.8
                            H0.1z M8.4,7.3v4.1h-7V5.6H6v3.2H2.9V9h3.2V5.6h2.4V2.5h3.8v6h2.8V8.3h-2.7V2.5h1.8v3h0.1v-3h1.4v3h-0.6v0.1h0.6v2.8h0l-1.3,2.1
                            H8.6V7.3H8.4z M18.9,5.7h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4h-0.6v0.1h0.6v1.4
                            h-0.6v0.1h0.6v0.8h-7.7l7.7-11.9V5.7z"/>
                        <path stroke="#1a1302" stroke-width="1.5" d="M17,10.2v3.7h-2.4L17,10.2L17,10.2z M17.1,9.8L14.4,14h2.7V9.8L17.1,9.8z"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
   </symbol>

  </g>
  
  <g id="itemsContainer"> 
   <a class="item" id="item-procurement" role="link" tabindex="0" transform="matrix(-0.80901,0.58778,-0.58778,-0.80901,599.2005616668552,305.30793552061857)" data-svg-origin="250 250">
    <path d="M415,250 l85,0 A250,250 0 0,0 327.25424859373686,12.235870926211618 l-26.26644452187054,80.83980388508806 A165,165 0 0,1 415,250" class="sector"></path>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-procurement-desktop" width="19" height="15.81" x="413.12713623046875" y="131.61793518066406" transform="rotate(-90 413.62713623046875 131.11793518066406)" />
   </a>  
  </g>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is all your problem, but your symbol's viewBox seems wrong to me. Shouldn't it be more like `"26 45 115 75"` ?

Comment: I agree with Kaido.  Your symbol has a bad viewBox.  You've tried to get around that by setting `overflow: visible` on the symbol.  That's a dodgy approach. Try fixing the viewBox and start from there. Calling getBBox() on the symbol suggests the viewBox should be set to `"0 0 140.2 119.9"`. When you do that, it becomes visible in FF. You then have a starting point to continue debugging.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Do you mean changing the viewBox on the first example, or doing it standalone just with the symbol? I tried altering the first example locally and had no luck in Firefox so I assume it is the latter?

Comment: I meant fixing the viewBox on the first example.